# Expo - Disable Autofill Strong Password (autofill) on iOS 12

Tags: ios, react-native, passwords, expo

On my application working on Expo, I would like to disable this functionality (strong password ios 12) : https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/

To be short, I would like to avoid [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm5Z4.png) (it's not my application)

I try different way like add those properties to my textInput

`textContentType='none'
autoCorrect={false}`

Nothing works...

Any guesses ?

Answer (score 3):

set `isSecureTextEntry` to false

then in your app delegate file add:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (textField == self.passwordTextField && !self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry) {
        self.passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

You may need to eject your app in order to open code in xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Found the only solution for this problem.

textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode

Otherwise iOS 12 uses PasswordAutofill for any secure field (textField.isSecureTextEntry = true).

Comment: This did not work for me. I still get the strong password suggestions on iOS 12.